# "if" statements not working - outputting certain code always user-input

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input, python-3.9

No matter what it always outputs `Spammer()`.

```
option = int(input("Enter the what you want to do: "))

<insert code not relevant>

if option == 1 or 'spam'.upper():
    Spammer()
elif option == 1:
    pcInfo()
```

Python 3.9.7
I've looked through several posts and nothing has worked.

edit: The typo was made while typing the code into StackOverflow. To fix the `if` statement I wrote it again but without `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-v` and it somehow worked.

Comment: @Alberto Hanna I removed .upper and replaced elif with if and the  same error persists.

Comment: In your *if* structure, are you trying to see if the user entered 1 or spam? Trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish with your 'spam'.upper()... anyway, they can't enter spam since you're casting the input to an int.

Answer (score 0):

As `'spam'.upper()` will return `'SPAM'`,
which will always give `True`.

also, the `pcInfo()` will never execute,
as it has the same condition `(option == 1)` as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

```
'spam'.upper()
```

will always return

```
SPAM
```

which is a non-empty string and therefore is regarded as a truthy statement by Python.

Since an if statement checks for truthy expressions, the if block will always be triggered.

If you need more help, please specify what you actually intend to with that statement.

Also: The else if block contains the same condition as the if block which I suppose is a typo? Otherwise if would always catch that case first and then skip over else if in all cases. So you should definitely use another value of the else if statement.